# ActiveDirectory PenTest Help

Tags: penetration-test, active-directory

I'm popped in the middle of the domain with what appears to be a VERY solid network. Good policy, good security, a lot of the usual tactics won't work. I cant pass-the-hash, find any SYSVOL loot, or gain access to any local users in any way.

They are pretty strict about patches. No local exploits to think of. I've tried eternalblue, smb exploits, powersploit, CME, etc...

All computers on the network do have a built-in Administrator account, however with CME I am unable to achieve anything meaningful.

When you are in the middle of a solid network, what's your usual workflow for finding a way to own a local machine to pivot your way to Domain Admin when it's hard to even get local creds?

On a side note, has anyone ever went into a pentest and been unable to achieve anything?

Comment: This seems to be off topic, as we don't answer how to break the security of a system unless a person demonstrates knowledge on the topic (which you do) **and** it is a clear and specific problem (which this isn't.)  You might get some good discussion and advice on how to proceed, but don't be surprised if the question gets closed.  (Not all good questions are right for StackExchange sites... That's not on you, that's just the site's standards of what's on topic.)

Comment: fair enough. I am new to this field so i would like learn from someone who has been around for awhile, but if it does get closed, im not mad. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @IgnitionK6 Try the chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz .Maybe you get some answers there

Answer (score 1):

Active directory penetration testing is an entire field of study with many attack vectors. BloodHound by SpecterOps looks for common active directory misconfigurations such as stale objects, incorrect ACL/DACL assignments, delegation issues, problems relating to trusts between AD forests and many more.

However, if stealth is a concern, BloodHound is quite noisy so an IR team or someone in the SOC could detect this so it is a risk to run that tool in a high security network. However, I still use it during engagements as the typical response time for this in my experience is 1 hour (it queries the domain controllers to get this info which is typically considered crowned jewels in enterprise, highly monitored).

This is typically enough time for me to pivot and establish persistence on another machine. BloodHound gives you a graph defining the shortest path to compromise (as they call it) of the domain (if possible).

There are also many old school tactics for compromising AD misconfigurations, I'll be attaching several links below. I hope you can find inspiration for a cool pwn in one of these links.

- https://www.slideshare.net/dafthack/pwning-the-enterprise-with-powershell
- https://www.slideshare.net/AndyRobbins3/six-degrees-of-domain-admin-bloodhound-at-def-con-24
- https://www.slideshare.net/harmj0y/i-hunt-sys-admins-20
- https://www.slideshare.net/harmj0y/not-a-security-boundary
- https://www.slideshare.net/harmj0y/ace-up-the-sleeve

Comment: This is insanely valuable information. I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I will look through the information provided. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.sans.org/webcasts/111735

Comment: Last link for you, kerberos attacks 101, I just watched it and it's very good. Covers ticket related attacks, kerberoasting as well as fundamentals.